# How to show most recent value in tableau BI?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau.

There is a dataset like this.

[image]

I want to show the `SUM(play_time) BY id`.
and also show name value together.

But the name value can be modified.
(So, name 'BBBB' is modified as 'BBBB new' when 2021.4.21)

Because id 2 has name 'BBBB', 'BBBB new', the `SUM(play_time)` is separated.
[image]

I want to show only name 'BBBB', how can I do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do that with this calculated field!

```
{ fixed [Show Id] : 
  max(if {fixed [Show Id] : max([Log Date])} == [Log Date]
    then [Show Name]
    else null
    end
  )
}
```

reference : https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2020/02/lod-uses.html